# fingerprint matching algorithm!

Tags: java, algorithm, matching, fingerprint, biometrics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iso 19794-2 fingerprint format.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817467/iso-19794-2-fingerprint-format)

Hi all,

I need to develop a system to match fingerprints. all fingerprints are already converted to **ISO 19794-2** format. the input will also be in ISO 19794-2 format. how to check whether the input and the fingerprints in database matches or not. is there any algorithm to implement it?

> i need *an algorithm to compare two fingerprints* in ISO 19794-2 format.

It would be more helpful if the answers are in Java perspective. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817467/iso-19794-2-fingerprint-format

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=38746 the standard provides some guidelines on how the records are to be matched.

Comment: is there any proven algorithm to do that?

Comment: @brainless, it's not just "an algorithm", but rather a whole bunch of different algorithms. Your question "as is", is (IMO) too open-ended to properly answer on SO. @Null Set gave you a good start, it's now up to you to do (a bit of) research.

Comment: @brainless Without access to the standard or more information about how these records are to be matched, no one is going to be able to tell you more.

Comment: if it doesn't invoke any copyright problem i can provide the doc for that standard. i have the genuine document. i can mail it to you personally.